# Using dates as a filter with Crossfilter

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

I'm trying to use the [Crossfilter](https://github.com/square/crossfilter) JavaScript library on a really large data set. I've simplified the data for this question.

```js
var tempArray = [

    {"date": new Date(2013, 6),"dataval":400,"col1":"Test 1","col2":"Billy Recycling Group","col3":"Billy Recycling Group - Mobile"},
    {"date": new Date(2013, 6),"dataval":400,"col1":"Test 1","col2":"Billy Recycling Group","col3":"Billy Recycling Group - Mobile"},
    {"date": new Date(2013, 6),"dataval":400,"col1":"Test 1","col2":"Billy Recycling Group","col3":"Billy Recycling Group - Mobile"},
    {"date": new Date(2013, 6),"dataval":400,"col1":"Test 1","col2":"Billy Recycling Group","col3":"Billy Recycling Group - Mobile"},

    {"date": new Date(2013, 6),"dataval":600,"col1":"Test 2","col2":"James Recycling Group","col3":"James Recycling Group - Mobile"},
    {"date": new Date(2013, 6),"dataval":600,"col1":"Test 2","col2":"James Recycling Group","col3":"James Recycling Group - Mobile"},
    {"date":new Date(2013, 6),"dataval":600,"col1":"Test 2","col2":"James Recycling Group","col3":"James Recycling Group - Mobile"},
    {"date":new Date(2013, 6),"dataval":600,"col1":"Test 2","col2":"James Recycling Group","col3":"James Recycling Group - Mobile"},

    {"date":new Date(2014, 6),"dataval":200,"col1":"Test 1","col2":"Billy Recycling Group","col3":"Billy Recycling Group - Mobile"},
    {"date":new Date(2014, 6),"dataval":200,"col1":"Test 1","col2":"Billy Recycling Group","col3":"Billy Recycling Group - Mobile"},
    {"date":new Date(2014, 6),"dataval":200,"col1":"Test 1","col2":"Billy Recycling Group","col3":"Billy Recycling Group - Mobile"},
    {"date":new Date(2014, 6),"dataval":200,"col1":"Test 1","col2":"Billy Recycling Group","col3":"Billy Recycling Group - Mobile"},

    {"date":new Date(2014, 6),"dataval":300,"col1":"Test 2","col2":"James Recycling Group","col3":"James Recycling Group - Mobile"},
    {"date":new Date(2014, 6),"dataval":300,"col1":"Test 2","col2":"James Recycling Group","col3":"James Recycling Group - Mobile"},
    {"date":new Date(2014, 6),"dataval":300,"col1":"Test 2","col2":"James Recycling Group","col3":"James Recycling Group - Mobile"},
    {"date":new Date(2014, 6),"dataval":300,"col1":"Test 2","col2":"James Recycling Group","col3":"James Recycling Group - Mobile"}

]

//**********************************************************************************
// Creating Crossfilter
//**********************************************************************************
var data = crossfilter(tempArray);

//**********************************************************************************
// Getting Dimension by Company Name
//**********************************************************************************
var dimensionByName = data.dimension(function (d) {return d.col1})

//**********************************************************************************
// Getting Dimension by Date
//**********************************************************************************
var dimensionByDate = data.dimension(function (d){return d.date})

//**********************************************************************************
// Dimension by Company name that I can use to get Data
//**********************************************************************************
var dim = data.dimension(function (d) {return d.col1})

dimensionByDate.filter(new Date(2014, 6))

var thisMonthMeasure = dim.group().reduceSum(function (d){return d.dataval});
console.log('thisMonthMeasure', thisMonthMeasure.top(Infinity))

//**********************************************************************************
// Clearing Data Filter
//**********************************************************************************
dimensionByDate.filterAll();

dimensionByDate.filter(new Date(2013, 6))
var lastYearMeasure = dim.group().reduceSum(function (d){return d.dataval});
console.log('lastYearMeasure', lastYearMeasure.top(Infinity))
```

The problem is that my code prints to the console the same array twice instead of two different arrays. The values are exactly the same so the results are this:

`thisMonthMeasure` is equal to  `[ {  key: "Test 2", value : 3600  }   ,  {  key: "Test 1", value : 2400  } ]`

`lastYearMeasure` is equal to `[ {  key: "Test 2", value : 3600  }   ,  {  key: "Test 1", value : 2400  } ]`

…instead of the expected results below:

`thisMonthMeasure` is equal to `[ {  key: "Test 2", value : 1200  }   ,  {  key: "Test 1", value : 800  } ]`

`lastYearMeasure` is equal to  `[ {  key: "Test 2", value : 2400  }   ,  {  key: "Test 1", value : 1600  } ]`

After some additional testing it appears as though my date filter isn't working.

How should I be filtering by the dates?

Link to JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TheMcMurder/u89Wv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that your 'date' attribute in your data is a string but that you're trying to filter using a Date object. Is that accurate? I don't think that will work. Maybe try

```
dimensionByDate.filter("2014-07-01T06:00:00.000Z");
```

Comment: That's not it. I am actually using dates but I updated the question to be a little more explicit

Comment: The groups are getting updated after they are written to the console. If you write out the actual values, you'll see that they change: http://jsfiddle.net/u89Wv/2/  You only actually need one group to do this - the group values update as you apply different filters.